# Equality comparison for Input iterators

Tags: c++, iterator, input-iterator

For input iterators, what are the requirements for comparing equality if one of the iterators has been invalidated?

```
input_iter x = foo();
input_iter y = x;
++x;
return x == y;  // What must this return?
```

In the above example, dereferencing `y` would obviously be undefined, but is the result of an equality comparison like this defined? Reading [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/InputIterator), it's definitely the case that two input iterators must compare `true` if they actually are the same, since input iterators must satisfy `EqualityComparable`, but I don't actually see anything that says what the result must be if the are *not* the same. Am I allowed to *always* return `true` from `operator==` (except when comparing against the end iterator)?

Comment: It seems implied that you should return `false` if they're not equivalent, but you're right, it's not explicitly stated, which is odd. It's worth noting that `x != y` is defined as being equivalent to `!(x == y)` so that might force your hand here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"*For input iterators, what are the requirements for comparing equality if one of the iterators has been invalidated?*"

There are none. Quoting *ISO/IEC 14882:2003(E), [lib.input.iterators]*,

> `==` is an equivalence relation **over its domain**, (emphasis added)
>   `bool(a==b) != bool(a!=b)` **over the domain of `==`** (emphasis added)

And,

> any copies of the previous value of `r` [prior to `++r`] are no longer
>   ... in the domain of `==`.

There is no requirement that `==` or `!=` have any particular behavior with respect to invalidated input iterators.

Comment: To be clear, you are saying the standard does not define the behaviour of `x==y` in the question?

Comment: So is the expression unspecified behaviour or undefined behaviour?

Comment: @M.M That would depend upon the precise type of `input_iter`. Since OP doesn't specify what `input_iter` is, other than it satisfies [lib.input.iterators], the behavior might be defined or it might not be.